# Getting second value in jQuery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I get the second value in a dropdown list using javascript or jquery?

```
<select id='dropdown'>
<option selected>Any</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

e.g. i would like to get the value of number 2 in the dropdown

Comment: Are you trying to select the item after the selected option or just the second option?

Comment: There is no value defined for any of the options. Do you mean to take `text` or `value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Neither of those options has a value.</s> *(Actually, see note below.)* You can get the text like this:

```
var text = $("#dropdown")[0].options[1].text;
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var text = document.getElementById("dropdown").options[1].text;
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uzudas/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/uzudas/1/edit)

Or you can use `.value` instead of `.text`, as the `option` elements will [default their `value` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-value) if you don't give them a `value` attribute. (You can't *select* them using a `value=` selector, but the *property* is defaulted.)

Comment: @alex23: With jQuery, **everything** is a set. So `$("#dropdown")` returns a *set* of elements (with one entry). The `[0]` gives us that one entry (the raw DOM element), from which we get the `options`...

Answer (score 2):

To get the **`second`** value in a dropdown list using jquery, you can do this using [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var text = $("#dropdown option").eq(1).text();
```

In order, to get the **`n`** th number value in the dropdown list, you can do this:

```
var text = $("#dropdown option").eq(n - 1).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#dropdown option').eq(1).val());
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9qCR/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this so easy to understand then :eq(n)

http://jsfiddle.net/q9qCR/2/

```
$('#dropdown option:nth-child(2)').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("#dropdown option").eq(1).text());
});
```